# JQuery Sliding doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, slider

I currently have most of my page and code working, however, I'm stumped on this jQuery animation part. I'm using tabs and the content of the `<div>`'s changes depending on the tab that is clicked. This works however, the content is supposed to slide out and change. Instead it is just changing instantly with no animation. I've put it into jFiddle, but I can't figure out why it's not working. And due to the fact that I couldn't seem to get the page to display correctly if I just cut out the code that relates to this specific issue, I had to insert the whole HTML and CSS code into jFiddle. I used this tutorial as a guide in creating the sliding feature that isn't sliding: 
http://www.queness.com/post/655/jquery-moving-tab-and-sliding-content-tutorial

Here is the jFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/LxjN2/1/

The idea is to have the text inside the box slide out. But for some reason it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://roko.x10.mx/xcSlider/ Something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you were not including the scrollTo plugin, which the tutorial was including from [here](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scrollto/js/jquery.scrollTo.js)

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxjN2/9/

Also note that when you create a fiddle, putting your JavaScript in the JavaScript part helps to see things with more clarity. To put that back in the html just add everything in the JavaScript panel to your `document.ready()`.

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed that in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

@citizen is correct.  To add to the explanation slightly:

The reason it was working at all is that the `scrollTo` was blowing up prior to `return false`.  Since the `return false` was never run, the default click functionality was allowed to execute which was to move to the anchor in the `href`.  This is why it was appearing instantly.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation.